# laravel paginator is producing wrong html links, goes from 1 to 3 without 2

Tags: jquery, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.6, jquery-jscroll

No idea what's going on here. However I am trying to user jScroll on a page, I successfully used it in another one but it's not working here.
I noticed that the links generated by laravel are incomplete.
They go something like this:
< 1 3 4 5 6 7 >

if I got to page 3 then I get:

< 1 2 3 5 6 7 > etc.

The controller is doing a query like this:

```
$posts_with_comments = Post::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
            $query->latest();
            $query->with('author');
        },

            'user' => function ($q) {

                $q->select('id', 'username');
            },

            'related_data'])
            ->where('user_id', $publisher->id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(9);
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel is this?

Comment: 5.6.26 actually I just found out that it's jScroll that is hiding the links. However jScroll is not triggered at full page width, it only works if I switch the view to something like "galaxy s5" or "iphone 6".